# How can I create a C2 VM on GCP?

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud

When I try to create a c2-standard-4 VM in the central region, I always get an error "Quota 'C2_CPUS' exceeded. Limit: 1.0 in region us-central1." (other regions have limit 0.0).  There is no way to request an increase either, CPUs is not listed on the Quota page.  Never mind the wisdom of offering 2-CPU VMs when the limit is < 2, what do I need to do to create this VM?

Thanks

Gregg

Answer (score 1):

My hypothesis is your CPUs (All Regions) quota is set to zero. If this is the case, maybe your usage history is very limited and as such the request might not be able to be accepted at the moment.

Please check [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#cpus) document and check your CPU (All Regions) quota.

You may need to delete existing instances before you can launch new instances.

Although I believe you know how to request for increasing the quotas, here is the [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#request_quotas) about it.